# How to check if __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ can be used?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

`...../PluginLoader.h:34: multiple definition of 'Dummy_Func_For_Generating_FUNCTION_NAME_Macro()'`

The above error is output for the below code. I have include guards in my file. And everything else compiles fine.

EDIT: What I was trying to achieve was to check if `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` was defined, and if it was, use it later in code via `FUNCTION_NAME` macro (For logging purposes). If `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is not defined, use next best thing and so on. However, the responses I got made me realize that this impossible. So, if `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` and all these others are not macros, what are they? And how do I check if a certain implementation has one of them or not?

```
    void Dummy_Func_For_Generating_FUNCTION_NAME_Macro()
    {
#ifndef FUNCTION_NAME
    #ifdef __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
        #define FUNCTION_NAME __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
    #elif __FUNCTION__
        #define FUNCTION_NAME __FUNCTION__
    #elif __func__
        #define FUNCTION_NAME __func__
    #else
        #define FUNCTION_NAME ""
    #endif
#endif
    }
```

Comment: what is the value of `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, `__FUNCTION__` and `__func__` ?

Comment: @Adrien: these are predefined macros, but not all are implemented for all compilers.

Comment: Did you place this function in a header?  If the header is included multiple times, the compiler may complain that it finds the same function more than once.

Comment: [Ask about the goal, not the step.](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) Nobody can help you if they don't understand what you're trying to do. So "What's wrong here" is "Who knows? You tell us." As far as I know your goal is to generate compile errors; nothing wrong here.

Comment: @GMan: I am not trying to produce compiler errors. I am just trying to get `FUNCTION_NAME` defined correctly. And I have clearly asked my question in the title.

Comment: Even if you fix the problem `FUNCTION_NAME` will always be defined as `Dummy_Func_For_Generating_FUNCTION_NAME_Macro`, no matter where you use it. Is that what you want?

Comment: @nakiya: No, you haven't. Your title is unclear. What "this macro" are you talking about? I see a function, and some macros that happen to reside in it. **Why** are they there? **What** are you attempting to do that made you do that? Those are the things you need to explain.

Comment: @GMan: Edited. Hope that makes things clearer.

Comment: @nakiya: where in the title does it say "I am just trying to get `FUNCTION_NAME` defined correctly? You asked your question in a comment. The actual question body and title didn't tell us what you were trying to do.

Comment: @jalf: Well, for all this nit-picking, no one gave me a hint how to do what I want :).

Comment: @nakiya: The solution is in my answer. Use `_MSC_VER` to identify `__FUNCTION__`. Handle all other compilers accordingly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`void Dummy_Func_For_Generating_FUNCTION_NAME_Macro()` is a function, not a macro. Functions don't create macros. Macros are resolved in preprocessor phase, and functions in compiler phase. Remove the function definition, <strike>and leave only `#ifndef` block.</strike>

Use compiler identifying macros to figure out which function identifying macro to use. For instance:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER // Visual Studio
    #define FUNCTION_NAME __FUNCTION__
#endif
```

Comment: But `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, `__FUNCTION__` and `__func__` are only ever defined *within a function* !

Comment: @Paul R, macro define should have no scope

Comment: Use `FUNCTION_NAME` in a function that you're actually interested in, and not in dummy function, where it will always resolve to dummy.

Comment: @Dialecticus: I'm just ensuring that `FUNCTION_NAME` is defined. Exactly because preprocessor runs before compiler, I can know what macro to use.

Comment: It is not possible to do that. You must check the compiler (each has special identifying macro, and a version as well), instead of checking the existence of function-scope macros.

Comment: @Dialecticus: Which is besides the point. Why does the function definition give an error?

Comment: Put the function definition in .cpp, and only function declaration in .h

Comment: +1:  This answer is spot on.  Drop the function.  It is multiply defined because you are putting it in a header file without an inline.  The methodology described in the answer is the perfect solution, IMO :)

Comment: @Goz : So, if I inline the function, will the error go away? I am not planning to use that method, just want to know. Why is it so?

Comment: Answer from kriss explains that `__FUNCTION__` is not really a preprocessor macro. It is defined in compile time, and not in preprocessing time. Preprocessor does not recognize it.

Comment: Kriss' answer is the actual answer to your question. I merely tried to give you the answer to a question you sould have really asked.

Comment: +1. I'm going to accept this though there should be some way to offer acceptance to more than one answer in which case I could have accepted Kriss' answer as well. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

`__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` and `__FUNCTION__` are not preprocessor macros like `__LINE__` or `__FILE__`, but magic constants they are not available at preprocessor time, but later at compile time (in function scope).

So whatever you are trying to do with macros here will probably not work anyway.

However the compiling error is probably a problem with guard. I succeed compiling a not very different program (see below) without any problem. But as I said above, FUNCTION_NAME will always be set to empty string.

xx.h header file

```
#ifndef H_XX_H
#define H_XX_H

#ifndef FUNCTION_NAME
    void Dummy_Func_For_Generating_FUNCTION_NAME_Macro()
    {
    #ifdef __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
        #define FUNCTION_NAME __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
    #elif __FUNCTION__
        #define FUNCTION_NAME __FUNCTION__
    #elif __func__
        #define FUNCTION_NAME __func__
    #else
        #define FUNCTION_NAME ""
    #endif
   ;
   }
#endif
#endif
```

xx.c source file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "xx.h"

main(){
    printf("%s\n", FUNCTION_NAME);
}
```

Comment: `__GUARD` [is reserved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier), don't use it.

Comment: OK, I guess you are not reacting over the `__guard` keyword but on the double leading underscore.

Comment: +1, I did not realise that the __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ et al constants were not initialised until compile time, in retrospect, it seems obvious :)

Answer (score 0):

I used to met this problem, which is caused by mounted disk:

> subst R: C:\Source\

Test.cpp:

```
 #include "C:\Source\PluginLoader.h"  
 #include "R:\PluginLoader.h"
```

Now if you include guard is #pragma once, the compiler is not smart enough to know that they are actual one file, thus cause the redefinition error.

However, I am not sure whether this is your problem, as it depends on:

- You include from both virtual disk,
  and physical disk
- Your include guard is #pragma once, not the macro guard

.

Answer (score 0):

Put your function in an `anonymous namespace`.  That will eliminate the `duplicate function` definition `errors`.   I.e.

```
 namespace {
     function goes here
  }
```