# Predefined Macros for function name __func__

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, c-preprocessor

I am attempting to build a debug log message function that records the file, line, and function of of where the log message was called from.

```
#define DEBUG_PANIC(p) CLogging::Debuglogf( "Debug marker (%s) - ::%s() in file: %s(%d)", p, __func__ , __FILE__, __LINE__ );
```

The above code works on some compilers but not all. My code needs to be cross compatible with GCC as well as Microsoft Visual studios. I have added the below defines to help with compatibility.

```
#ifndef __FUNCTION_NAME__
    #if defined __func__ 
        // Undeclared 
        #define __FUNCTION_NAME__   __func__ 
    #elif defined __FUNCTION__ 
        // Undeclared
        #define __FUNCTION_NAME__   __FUNCTION__  
    #elif defined __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
        // Undeclared
        #define __FUNCTION_NAME__   __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
    #else
        // Declared
        #define __FUNCTION_NAME__   "N/A"   
    #endif // __func__ 

#endif // __FUNCTION_NAME__

#define DEBUG_PANIC(p) CLogging::Debuglogf( "Debug marker (%s) - ::%s() in file: %s(%d)", p, __FUNCTION_NAME__, __FILE__, __LINE__ );
```

The problem with the above code snippet is that it is the #else macro is active on all compilers while the other macros are not. in other words `#if defined __func__` is false on compilers where `__func__` is a *predefined macro*.

My question is

- How do I create a cross compiler macro to find the function name ?
- How can I tell if a `__func__` can be used?

Comment: Are you writing C or C++?

Comment: @KeithThompson Sorry I forgot to add that to the question, Yes C++

Comment: related: [What's the difference between `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, `__FUNCTION__`, `__func__`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384765/whats-the-difference-between-pretty-function-function-func).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You're assuming `__func__` is a macro, but it's not. It's a conditionally-supported predefined identifier, so you can't check it with `#if defined` or `#ifdef`.

If the compilers have no way of telling you whether this is supported (they could via a `_FUNC_SUPPORTED` or something, I'm not saying they actually are doing this), you'll have to check the compiler instead of the actual identifier.

Something along the lines:

```
#ifndef __FUNCTION_NAME__
    #ifdef WIN32   //WINDOWS
        #define __FUNCTION_NAME__   __FUNCTION__  
    #else          //*NIX
        #define __FUNCTION_NAME__   __func__ 
    #endif
#endif
```

Comment: Any C compiler conforming to C99 or later *must* support `__func__`; in that sense, it's not an optional feature. So one way to tell that `__func__` is supported is by checking `__STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L`. (Though a pre-C99 or non-conforming compiler could support it as an extension.)

Comment: @KeithThompson I was assuming C++. But the main point was that it's not a macro.

Comment: Ah, good point; the OP didn't add a tag for the language. The C++ standard didn't mandate `__func__` until 2011. It's probably a common extension for pre-C++11 compilers.

Answer (score 19):

As often [Boost](http://www.boost.org) is THE cross platform solution with [`BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/boost/current_function.hpp) defined in `<boost/current_function.hpp>`.

Answer (score 12):

I would like to add that the `__FUNCTION__` macro is defined for both GCC and MSVC. Though non-standard, it is available on both compilers.

[GCC Standard Predefined Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html) quote:

> C99 introduces `__func__`, and GCC has provided `__FUNCTION__` for a long time. Both of these are strings containing the name of the current function (there are slight semantic differences; see the GCC manual). Neither of them is a macro; the preprocessor does not know the name of the current function. They tend to be useful in conjunction with `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`, though.

[MSVC Predefined Macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) quote:

> `__FUNCTION__`
>
> Valid only in a function. Defines the undecorated name of the enclosing function as a string literal.
>
> `__FUNCTION__` is not expanded if you use the /EP or /P compiler option.
>
> See `__FUNCDNAME__` for an example.

So using `__FUNCTION__` would be ok, since both compilers implement it. Though you may not get the same results on both compilers but that might be acceptable in some situations.

Comment: _I would like to add that the `__FUNCTION__` macro is defined for both GCC and MSVC._ the documentation quote explicitly states that this is **not** a macro.

Answer (score 7):

> they are neither preprocessor macros, like `__FILE__ and __LINE__`,
>   nor variables.

Taken from the following link:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Function-Names.html

Also, please check out this other question that was answered that is similar to yours:

[How to check if __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ can be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164315/how-to-check-if-pretty-function-can-be-used)

Example:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER // Visual Studio
    #define FUNCTION_NAME __FUNCTION__
#endif
```