# Destringification in the gcc preprocessor

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Is it possibly to write a gcc macro that destringifies a string literal argument? I know the opposite is possible with `#`. Can it be reversed?

For example, `__func__`  evaluates to the name of the current function in the form of a string literal. Can I remove the double quotation marks around it?

Comment: [`__func__` is not a macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305310/predefined-macros-for-function-name-func)

Comment: I don't think it is possible and you can't spare defining a macro to hold the function name.

Answer (score 7):

No, it is not possible to convert `"foo"` to `foo` using the standard C/C++ preprocessor. If you absolutely need this, you would need to create an external preprocessing program, similar to what Qt does with its `moc` tool.

Not completely on-topic, but the D language has exactly this functionality - it's called [mixins](http://dlang.org/mixin.html). You can execute arbitrary string processing code at compile time and "paste" the result into your source file with the `mixin` keyword.

Comment: Thanks. Great answer!