# Calling the same function without knowing the name?

Tags: c++

I am looking for a way to call the same function (with different parameters) **without knowing the function name**. Something like this:

```
void my_func(int x)
{
    //...
    SELF(x-5);
    //...
}
```

I need to use the above because I have some complex macros. An example of why I need this:

```
#define start_func if(id == 0) return SELF();

int A(int id) { start_func /*...*/ }
int B(int id) { start_func /*...*/ }
int C(int id) { start_func /*...*/ }
int D(int id) { start_func /*...*/ }
int E(int id) { start_func /*...*/ }
int F(int id) { start_func /*...*/ }

int A() { /*...*/ }
int B() { /*...*/ }
int C() { /*...*/ }
int D() { /*...*/ }
int E() { /*...*/ }
int F() { /*...*/ }
```

Comment: I don't understand why my question was down-voted?

Comment: What do you mean?  Are you asking if you can call a function in itself (this is called a recursive function, and you can), or are you asking if you can call another function multiple times (if so, use a for loop)?  Edit: Just saw your comment, I didn't downvote but I'd assume someone thought it was unclear probably

Comment: This question is ridiculous. I have not explained ANYTHING about it and about the problem with your code.

Comment: how can you not know the function name? it's right there on the first line of code you posted. Unless you're writing a closure, you always have to know/specify the name of the function.

Comment: @Marc B I don't know the name because I am using macros.

Comment: It may help to show an actual example where you need to call the function but you do not know its name.

Comment: then you should show the macros you're using.

Comment: I don't even dare to hint that setjmp / longjmp can do this as long as arguments are non-const :D.

Comment: Short answer: I don't think you can do this portably.  However, if you can show us why you need the macro, we might be able to show you a better way than using the macro.

Comment: @lorro `longjmp` is like `goto`². It leads to a lot of FUN.

Comment: @all added example

Comment: The simple solution is to make the macro take the function name as a parameter. So `int A(int id) { start_func(A) /*...*/ }`.

Comment: @David Schwartz This **is** a solution but isn't there any better way?

Comment: Another good reason to not use macros. I feel sorry for a person debugging and maintaining the code

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305310/predefined-macros-for-function-name-func

Comment: @kfsone this will return the name of the function as string, right? Is there any way to use that string to call the function?

Comment: I was actually trying to underline the lack of a standard way to get the "current function name" at the pre-processor stage. I hit return too soon.

Comment: @kfsone OK, thanks for the help! :D

Comment: Why not to pass a pointer to the function as one of the parameters and call that pointer inside the function?

Comment: @Outtruder Because this is not an elegant way to do the job. But it's simple and it works.

Comment: Looking at your example: Why are you abusing overloading in this way, rather than simply using default arguments: `int A (int id = 0) { if (id == 0) { /* default/zero code */ } else { /* non-zero code */ } }`?

Comment: @acwaters Because the code is doing something completely different.

Comment: if it is doing something completely different then why does `A(int)` and `A` even have the same name?

Comment: @MATH000 Wait, do you mean that in the example, `A(int)` and `A()` do completely different things -- in which case, why are they named the same and disambiguated by only a parameter? -- or that the example is not indicative of your actual problem -- in which case, why bother writing it if it doesn't help us help you? Anyway, there is no way to do what you're asking. Why don't you show us your *actual* code so that we can help you find an alternate solution that doesn't involve complex macros or nonexistent preprocessor directives?

Comment: @tobi303 There is good reason. Basically the A() function needs the results of the A(1), A(2) etc functions to work.

Comment: @acwaters This is my actual code.

Comment: @MATH000 Alright, then the example I just gave using default arguments and no macros behaves the same as the hypothetical examples you gave above. I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: @acwaters Thanks for the help! Your solution is actually solving the problem but maybe there is a solution that keeps the code structure like I have it now?

Comment: why do you want to keep the code structure? Having an overload that does something completely different is at best confusing

Comment: @MATH000 You could always write another function to do the dispatching: `int A (int id = 0) { if (id == 0) return defaultA(); else return paramaterizedA(id); }`, and then if you *really* wanted to you could change out `defaultA` and `paramaterizedA` for function overloads as you have in your example, e.g. `int A_()` and `int A_(int)` -- then the structure of the code would be as you have it now, with one extra function per function overload pair (although I really cannot discourage this enough).

Comment: @MATH000 Better in what way? Obscuring the fact that the macro needs to call the function it's in makes things worse, not better.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this nasty thing, but it sort of works. It can call itself, with different parameters, but not different function with same name (overload). Also, it does not support default parameters.

```
#define BEGIN_FUNC(ret, name, ...) ret name(__VA_ARGS__) { ret(*SELF)(__VA_ARGS__) = name;
#define END_FUNC }

BEGIN_FUNC(int, factorial, int n)
    return n == 0 ? 1 : n * SELF(n - 1);
END_FUNC

int main()
{
    factorial(5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the predefined variable `__func__` to get the name of the current function.  Does that help?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks for the edit, I had not realized `__func__` is actually a constexpr variable.  According to gcc's documentation though it would seem `__func__` is standard in C99 but not in C++.  So it is still a compiler-specific solution is it not?

Comment: It's a part of C++, but surprisingly it's more or less new. It was added in C++11.